# Are "cat > filename << EOF" and "cat << EOF > filename" equivalent?

Tags: bash, heredoc

`cat > filename << EOF` vs `cat << EOF > filename`

When I tested it, it looks like they are equivalent but I'm not fully understanding why that is the case.

I understand the purpose of this command is to continually STDOUT into filename until I type EOF and then CTRL-D.

`cat > filename << EOF` (in terms of its sequence) makes sense to me: output stuff into filename until I hit EOF to tell it to stop.

But I was surprised that `cat << EOF > filename` works too. I've been told that bash reads from left to right. In this case, how is my STDOUT getting to filename?

Comment: Redirections are processed left-to-right, but _all_ the redirections have to be complete before `cat` can be started (until the redirections are done, the process's file handles aren't ready, so it can't be invoked yet).

Comment: `cat >filename <<EOF` doesn't really mean "send stuff to filename until you type EOF". What it really means is "connect filename to stdout, then connect stdin to a temporary file that has everything I'm about to type up to EOF in it, and then run the program `cat`". Note that `cat` doesn't start until _after_ you typed the `EOF`!

Answer (score 0):

`<< EOF` controls what goes to `cat`'s stdin.

`> filename` controls where `cat`'s stdout goes.

It doesn't matter which order the two are applied, the result is the same. And, of course, it's `cat` that handles copying its input to its output.